# Get attribute from selected model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `PHP 7.1.33` and `Laravel Framework 5.8.36`.

I am getting a model back by name like the following `Product::where('name', '=', $name)->get();`

My `Product` model looks like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'product';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'url', 'category'];
}
```

When trying to get an attribute like the following I get an error:

```
$product = Product::where('name', '=', $name)->get();
$product->$url; // ERROR
$product->$category; // ERROR
```

Any suggestions how to access the attributes on my retrieved model?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use `get()` if you only expect a single Model instance.** `->get()` returns a `Collection`, and you can't access a single property without looping.

Use `->first()`, or a similar method like `firstOrFail()`, `find()`, `findOrFail()`, etc.:

```
$product = Product::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
$product->$url;
$product->$category;
```

If you're expecting multiple instances, then you may use `->get()` in conjunction with a loop:

```
$products = Product::where('name', '=', $name)->get();
foreach($products AS $products){
  $product->$url;
  $product->$category;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$product = Product::whereName($name)->first();
$product->$url;
$product->$category;
```

Answer (score 1):

from your query you will get many collection of data so you have to access like this

```
$products = Product::where('name', '=', $name)->get();

foreach($products as $product){
  dd($product->$url,$product->$category);
}
```

but i think you if you have one data for particular name use **`first()`**

```
$product = Product::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
dd($product->$url,$product->$category);
```